# cannot set App Name and PySparkShell persists in Spark History Server

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I am having an issue on using PySpark with Google Cloud Dataproc. Currently, I have 2 similar clusters; one is **autoscale** and another is **no-autoscale**. When I declare Spark session with a specific app name on *no-autoscale* cluster, it seems fine to me both on notebook and Spark History Server with app name of `modddddddd` as I attached the picture below

[image]

---

However, on *autoscale* cluster, it doesn't work the same as previous cluster
[image]

And I looked up its app name on Spark History Server, it keeps saying `PySparkShell` instead of `modddddddd`.

I have tried to search for a solution but I found none. Is there anyway to solve this issue? Since this *autoscale* cluster has a lot of users, it's best for logging history on backend corresponding to individual app name.

Thank you in advance!